# php shared memory and semaphore, avoid key collision

Tags: php, semaphore, shared-memory

In using php shared memory and semaphores. How can I first check that the key for the semaphore and shared memory block, doesn't collide with other instances of php?  Also when using the shm_attach function to create a new block, is there a way to verify the block didn't already already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're asking here. The whole point of shared memory is that it is *shared* - so being able to use the same key in different instances of PHP is pretty much a requirement.

Typically people use filesystem paths (semantically meaningful) to generate keys (not meaningful) via the ftok() function. If you want to generate a random key not shared by any other php instance, then use tempnam() to create a new file, and then ftok it.

> when using the shm_attach function to create a new block, is there a way to verify the block didn't already already exist?

Yes - put something in there after you create it. If it was empty in between these 2 steps then it's new.

Comment: Let's say you're using 100 different semaphores for 100 different tasks that should not collide, somehow you want to keep track of them right, that's what he's asking. So generating based in path name is a way to make that sure.